# How to set minDate for ng-bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

Below is the code I am using to set the minDate

```
 <input ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker"  [minDate]="minDate" [formControl]="Form.controls['dateOfBirth']">
```

In the component  I am setting the minDate as below:

```
public minDate: Date = void 0; 
constructor() {
    this.minDate = new Date(1950, 1, 1);
}
```

But the datepicker still shows 2007 as the minDate. Is there any thing that is missing. Let me know in case any other information is required.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From your code snippet it looks like you are using **ng-bootstrap** from https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker. Assuming that I'm correct you need to use `NgbDateStruct` (an object with fields like `year`, `month`, `day`) instead of the built-in JavaScript `Date` object. For example, to set a min date to the beginning of this year you would use:

```
this.minDate = {year: 2017, month: 1, day: 1};
```

Here is a working example in a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/VDEYDwp7QIZDDHatCNPh?p=preview

Answer (score 9):

Just pass `[minDate]="{year: 1980, month: 1, day: 1}"`:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="date"  ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (focus)="d.open()" [minDate]="{year: 1980, month: 1, day: 1}" name="date" class="form-control"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your HTML Code

```
<mat-form-field class="col-md-3">
<mat-label >Date :</mat-label>
<input
matInput
ngxDaterangepickerMd
formControlName="dateFilter"
placeholder="Choose date"  [maxDate]="maxDate" [minDate]="minDate"
[showDropdowns]="true"
[singleDatePicker]="true"
[showCancel]="true"
 [locale]="locale"
/>
 </mat-form-field>
```

This goes to typescript:

```
public minDate =  moment().subtract(1, 'days');
public maxDate = moment();
selected = moment();
locale :LocaleConfig= {
    applyLabel: 'Apply',
    customRangeLabel: ' - ',
    daysOfWeek: moment.weekdaysMin(),
    monthNames: moment.monthsShort(),
    firstDay: moment.localeData().firstDayOfWeek(),
};
```