# minDate is throwing an error in bsDatepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker

I am trying to set the minimum date for my bootstrap datepicker but things are not working as expected. Here's my html code :

```
<input type="text" name="dateEnd"
       [ngModel]="contract.dateEnd | dateFormat" [minDate]="minimumDate"
       (ngModelChange)="contract.dateEnd = formatDate($event)"
       class="form-control" bsDatepicker required>
```

My Ts :

```
public minimumDate;

ngOnInit(): void {
  //skipped source code
  this.minimumDate = {year: this.getMinDate().getFullYear(), month: this.getMinDate().getMonth() , day: this.getMinDate().getDay()}; //respect the NgDateStruct type format
}

getMinDate() : Date {
  var sysdate = new Date();
  sysdate.setDate(sysdate.getDate() + 1);
  return sysdate;
}
```

I tried to do just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43053293/13919748) except that I am required to use `bsDatepicker` while in the given answer we are using an `ngbDatepicker`. Moreover my `minimumDate` is conform with the `NgDateStruct` type mentioned in the official [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api). Also when removing the `[minDate]` from my html the datePicker works just fine as before, but once added the datePicker is not even displayed and in the console I am getting this error message instead : `ERROR TypeError: date.getTime is not a function`.

Comment: @javaistaucheineisel Please my answer and let me know. Best wishes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a solution how you can set minDate for `bsDatepicker`. I did that in little different way. To learn different function and activity of `bsDatepicker` you can check the link [BSDatePicker LINK](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#reactive)
Please check and let me know it works for you or not.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="dateEnd"
         [ngModel]="mySelectedDate" 
         (ngModelChange)="dateChanged($event)"
         [minDate]="minDate"
        [maxDate]="maxDate"
       class="form-control" bsDatepicker required>
```

**TS:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  minDate: Date;
  maxDate: Date;
  mySelectedDate: any;
  constructor() {
    this.minDate = new Date();
    this.maxDate = new Date();
    this.minDate.setDate(this.minDate.getDate() - 1);
    this.maxDate.setDate(this.maxDate.getDate() + 7);
  }
  dateChanged($event) {
    this.mySelectedDate = $event;
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** I have created small demo of given code for you in Stackblitz [Link of Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-bsdatepicker-bug-2-c9zdsd). Please check and let me know.